# check all mount point are mounted according to fstab file

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

what is the best approach to check all mount point are mounted according to fstab file

my target is to check that all mountpoint as defined in fstab are really mounted

what is the command for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mount --fake --verbose --all
```

For currently mounted devices the output will contain *"already mounted"*.

Options explained (for exact details see [`man 8 mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mount.8.html#contenttoc3)):

- `--fake`: mount command will not actually mount anything
- `--verbose`: provide detailed output
- `--all`: mount all devices listed in *fstab*

Comment: `-a for --all` and `-v` for `--verbose` also works.