# Comparing mounted-mount points with fstab

Tags: bash, scripting, mount

I took the sample script, below, off the net to check and validate mount points of system that is already up and running.

**The problem:**
I want to compare existing mounted-mount points which are not commented out in the `/etc/fstab` and highlighting them *if* they are on.

Also, I would like to inquire if there is any alternative solution!

```
#!/bin/bash
while read ip;
do
    echo "connecting to $ip";
    ssh root@$ip "until mount | grep -w \"/mnt/data\" >/dev/null;
     do echo mounting \"/mnt/data\"; mount \"/mnt/data\"; sleep 1; done && 
     echo Mounted on $ip"
done < ips.txt
```

Comment: That script looks for **one** mount point  (`/mnt/data`) on a bunch of servers.  That's not what you want.

Comment: Do you want: the list of currently-mounted filesystems that are *not* "active" in /etc/fstab, or do you want: the list of "active" entries in /etc/fstab that are not mounted?

Comment: Linking in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/395721/117549

Answer (score 2):

This appears to do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
mountpoints=( $(awk '$1 !~ /^#/ && $2 ~ /^[/]/ {print $2}' /etc/fstab) )
for mount in ${mountpoints[@]}; do
   if ! findmnt "$mount" &> /dev/null; then
      echo "$mount is declared in fstab but not mounted"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Stealing</strike> borrowing DopeGhoti's `awk`, you could use `comm` for this:

Filesystems that are mounted but not in /etc/fstab:

```
comm -23 <(mount|awk '{print $3}'|sort) <(awk '$1 !~ /^#/ && $2 ~ /^[/]/ {print $2}' /etc/fstab|sort)
```

Filesystems that are in /etc/fstab but not mounted:

```
comm -13 <(mount|awk '{print $3}'|sort) <(awk '$1 !~ /^#/ && $2 ~ /^[/]/ {print $2}' /etc/fstab|sort)
```